# Count css selectors on a website

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am doing a presentation shortly about selectors on websites.  Is there an app, firefox plugin or something which allows me to count the number on a website?

I found this javascript ([link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/03/03/css-crunch-new-ie-extension-for-developers.aspx)) which works on some websites but not others like BBC and Facebook.

Any help is much appreciated.

Dave.

Comment: by the css selector do you mean the class and id on the webpage???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

[Firebug CSS Usage](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/css-usage/)

Answer (score 1):

In the Firebug console or Webkit Inspector console just type:

```
document.querySelectorAll('*').length;
```

Comment: Doesn't this count the number of elements in the DOM rather than the number of CSS selectors?